# Upgrading application to Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3 and getting undefined method `config_accessor' for SiteSweeper:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

I'm struggling through upgrading an app to Rails 3 (Ruby 1.8.7), and my current roadblock is when running 'rake test --trace' i get the following:

```
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Invoke test:units (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Invoke test:functionals (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare
** Execute test:functionals
DEPRECATION WARNING: "Rails.root/test/mocks/test" won't be added automatically to load paths anymore in future releases. (called from <APP PATH>/config/application.rb:17)
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.11/lib/action_controller/caching/pages.rb:47: undefined method `config_accessor' for SiteSweeper:Class (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/concern.rb:52:in `class_eval'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/concern.rb:52:in `append_features'
        from <APP PATH>/app/sweepers/site_sweeper.rb:4:in `include'
        from <APP PATH>/app/sweepers/site_sweeper.rb:4
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
...
```

The error here points to code that is actually inside the Rails 3.0.11 gem (action_controller/caching/pages.rb:47) and i can't figure out why that would cause problems or why i can't find any others having this problem.  I'm also looking for the docs for ActionController::Caching to see if 'config_accessor' would have gone away..?

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is a *complete* answer, but for the applications i'm upgrading the 'test/mocks' directory had nothing in it.  Removing the directory removed the deprecation messages.